# Index out of range when overwriting array that UI depends on

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a ForEach, that iterates over array of indices, accessing array's data by subscript, at some point in loading program from file process this array needs to be rewritten, thus its size is changed, but when the size of already rendered cells exceeds the new size the
`Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range` occurs.

```swift
ForEach(computer.program.commands.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                            GeometryReader { cell in
                                CommandCellView($computer.program[i],
                                        computer.program[i].number == computer.commandCounter.getValue())
                                        .renderIfWillBeSeen(preload, viewGeometry: cell, generalGeometry: g)
                            }.frame(height: cellHeight)
                        }
```

the `computer` is `@StateObject`, and everything inside of it is a `struct`

tried to call file method inside `withAnimation()` didn't work

works perfectly fine when rendered cell count is smaller than new array count

Comment: Hi! Your ForEach iterates over some indices. You use this index to get an object from computer.program. Don't you want to iterate over computer.program?
ForEach(computer.program, id: \.self, ....

Comment: This *sounds* like a "zero-based" issue. Nothing in your code - which BTW isn't anything duplicatable - assumes the `i` starts with zero. Usually I'd expect something to be `i-1` or something equivalent. Please, either (a) show enough code so we could duplicate, or (b) place a breakpoint or something to indicate the this variable `i` isn't out of range for `computer.program` count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, initial problem was to interate over binding of a collection in ForEach as if it was a collection of bindings. That functionality will be added in the new version of swift, however, I decided to post the solution that I found, in case someone will need that type of functionality in an older version of SwiftUI

### API

```swift
//$computer.program - Binding<MutableCollection<Command>>
//command - Binding<Command>
BindingForEach($computer.program) { command in
    CommandCellView(...,
                    command: command)
}
```

### BindingForEach.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BindingForEach<Data: MutableCollection, Content: View>: DynamicViewContent where Data.Index: Hashable,
                                                                                        Data.Indices == Range<Int> {
    @Binding public var data: Data
    private var builder: (Binding<Data.Element>) -> Content
    private var elementBindings = FunctionCache<Data.Index, Binding<Data.Element>>()
    
    init(_ collection: Binding<Data>, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping (Binding<Data.Element>) -> Content) {
        self._data = collection
        self.builder = content
        self.elementBindings = FunctionCache<Data.Index, Binding<Data.Element>> { [self] (i) in
            Binding<Data.Element> { [self] in
                self.data[i]
            } set: { [self] in
                self.data[i] = $0
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data.enumerated().map({ (i, _) in i }), id: \.self) { i in
            builder(elementBindings[i])
        }
    }
}
```

### FunctionCache.swift

It it important to cache created bindings, to optimize the performance

```swift
import Foundation

class FunctionCache<TSource: Hashable, TResult> {
    
    private let function: (TSource) -> (TResult)
    private var cache = [TSource : TResult]()
    
    init (_ function: @escaping (TSource) -> TResult = { _ in fatalError("Unspecified function") }) {
        self.function = function
    }
    
    subscript(_ i: TSource) -> TResult {
        get {
            if !cache.keys.contains(i) {
                cache[i] = function(i)
            }
            
            return cache[i]!
        }
    }
}
```